# Adding value to a cell in Numbers for Mac when a value already exists

Tags: macos, numbers

I have some data points in column A that I want to add 50 to across all cells in that column. How can I calculate that per cell without having to manually add 50 to every value?

Comment: Why don't you write a formula in one of the rows in column B adding 50 to the cell to its left and then copy and paste it to all rows in column B? If you haven't written a formula in Numbers before, the "[Calculate values using data in table cells in Numbers on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/numbers/calculate-values-using-data-in-table-cells-tan727173a8/mac)" Apple Support webpage might help.